# TOP16 Ⅱに対する5Vの出力指令のプログラムがわかりません．

Tags: arduino

当方，プログラミングは初心者です．
TOP16 ⅡというArduinoを使っておりまして，UbuntuベースのOSでgccでmakeされたソフトウェアからUSB端子に接続されたTOP16 Ⅱに任意のタイミングで5Vのトリガー信号を出力するプログラムを考えているのですが，一向にわからず困っております．
どなたかわかる方がいたら教えていただけないでしょうか．

Comment: 今の情報だけだと、質問者さんは何が分からないのか "第三者が分からない状態" です。例えば「プログラムはある程度書けるけどボードの制御が分からない」「そもそもプログラムを書くにはどうすればいいのか分からない」など、色々なケースが考えられます。 / [ボードの説明](https://www.elefine.jp/SHOP/TOP16-II.html) を見ると、「Visual BasicかVisual C# から制御可能」とありますが、なんの言語を使用されるかはご自身で想定していますか？

Comment: 失礼しました．プログラムも基礎的なことはわかっております．ボードの制御がわからない状態です．また言語はC++を想定してます．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これ http://www.tctec.net/top16_ii.htm のことだと思われます。
とりあえずこのボードの出力端子はオープンコレクタなので [5V を出力する] ことは回路上できません（この説明でわからない場合、先は長い）。また、メーカー側から提供されているツールが Windows 版のみ（かつ .NET Framework 向け) であるため Linux ベースしかも C++ で制御したいとなるとその辺から全部自作する必要がありそうです。つまり限りなくいばらの道を選んでいるように見えます。

やるべきこと

[5V を出力する] 回路をどう組むとよいか理解する（ハードウエアを理解する）
ボードに対してどう通信するとどう反応するかの仕様を調査する（ボードのファーム仕様を理解する）
その通信を Linux 上でどう実装するか理解する（ Linux の理解）
自分のやりたいことを実装する

となり、まあなかなか険しく長い道のりだと思います。今のこの質問だと答えるには本が数冊書けちゃう分量になるのでネット掲示板では困難（不可能）でしょう。数回の質疑応答で「回答」になれる分量の質問に細分化することをお勧めします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．出力端子がオープンコレクタだから [5V を出力する] ことが回路上できないということはわかってないです．書き方が間違ったかもしれませんが，元々あるプログラムにTOP16 ⅡをUSB接続し，そのプログラム内に別の装置へプログラムの任意のタイミングを知らせるデジタル指令信号を出力したいのですが(5V出力である必要はありません)，それも困難でしょうか？無理そうなら担当に相談いたします．わかりづらくて申し訳ありません．